# How to get hidden value in other Frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 frame

```
    <frameset rows="30%,*" frameborder="1" border="2" framespacing="0" >
        <frame name="right_t" name="menu" src=".../cart/asp/index.asp" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" >
        <frame name="right_b" src="...order/asp/Order.asp"" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto">
    </frameset>
```

I have a hidden value in frame name="right_t"

```
 <input type="hidden" id="basket" name="basket" value="true" />
```

but my problem is, I can't get the value of hidden value I used

```
  var sample= $('#basket', window.parent.frames[0].document)
```

but I don't know what is next how to get the value of basket hidden field.
any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var sample= top.frames["right_t"].document.getElementById('basket');
```

If doesnt work

Try this

```
var sample= 
top.document.getElementById("right_t").contentDocument.getElementById("basket");
```

Comment: I tried var sample= top.frames["right_t"].document.getElementById('basket'); but when I checked the value alert(sample.val()); error uncaugth type error.

Comment: what is alert(sample); ?

Comment: the value of <input type="hidden" id="basket" name="basket" value="true" /> is true or false, using top.document.getElementById("right_t").contentDocument.getElementById("basket");  I need to get the value of hidden if true or false.

Comment: what is alert(sample); ?  error uncaugth type error, I also used alert(sample.value()); same error

Comment: I got it var sample = top.frames["right_t"].document.getElementById('free_form_basket_order_in').value; thanks Vaibs_Cool

Comment: you have to get the value like this  $(sample).val();